# ElasticSearch - Parent Child Relationship

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to create parent child relationships using NEST client for C#. Here is the code I have. I am using elasticsearch 1.1.1 and this code seems to be adding the testp1 object to the testparent index but it is not adding any objects to the testchild index. If I do not pass a parent using the index parameters it seems to work fine. Any help regarding this is appreciated.

```
private static void LoadTestData()
{
    var esClient = CreateNESTConnection();
    esClient.MapFluent<testparent>(x => x
        .IndexName("testdb")
        .TypeName("testparent")
        .IdField(y => y.SetPath("Id"))
        .Properties(cprops => cprops
            .String(a => a.Name("id"))
            .Number(a => a.Name("parentid").Type(NumberType.@long))
            .Number(a => a.Name("prop1").Type(NumberType.@long))
            .Number(a => a.Name("prop2").Type(NumberType.@long))
            .Boolean(a => a.Name("checkflag"))
    ));

    esClient.MapFluent<testchild>(x => x
        .IndexName("testdb")
        .TypeName("testchild")
        .SetParent("testparent")
        .Properties(cprops => cprops
            .Number(a => a.Name("dockey").Type(NumberType.@long))
            .Number(a => a.Name("docvalue").Type(NumberType.@float))
    ));

    testparent testp1 = new testparent();
    testp1.checkflag = true;
    testp1.id = "7";
    testp1.parentid = 77;
    testp1.prop1 = 1;
    testp1.prop2 = 2;
    testchild testc1 = new testchild();
    testc1.dockey = 100;
    testc1.docvalue = 111;

    testchild testc2 = new testchild();
    testc2.dockey = 100;
    testc2.docvalue = 111;

    esClient.Index(testp1, "testdb");
    IndexParameters parameters = new IndexParameters();
    parameters.Parent = "7";
    var t = esClient.Index(testc1, "testdb", parameters);
    Console.WriteLine(t.OK);
    t = esClient.Index(testc2, "testdb", parameters);
    Console.WriteLine(t.OK);
}
```

Comment: you get any solution?